# Is it possible to call a super setter in ES6 inherited classes?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering if the following is in compliance with the ES6 spec:

```js
class X {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = name + "X";
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  set name(name) {
    super.name = name;
    this._name += "Y";
  }
}
```

The idea is that `let y = new Y(""); y.name = "hi"` should result in `y.name === "hiXY"` being true.

As far as I can tell, this doesn't work in Chrome with the ES6 flag turned on. It also doesn't work using Babel with the `es2015` flag. Is using `super.name = ...` in an inherited setter not part of the ES6 spec? Or is this a bug in the implementation of Babel?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? You are overriding the `get name` from the base class by defining `set name` on the child without a matching `get name(){ return super.name; }`. Is that the issue?

Comment: @DenysSéguret No, because I want the super's setter to run (adding an X to the end of the name).

Comment: @loganfsmyth You're right! I didn't realize defining `set name` would override `get name`. It does appear to work once I add the getter as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
class Y extends X {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  set name(name) {
    super.name = name;
    this._name += "Y";
  }
}
```

will override the `name` properly with an accessor for *just* the setter, with no getter. That means your `y.name === "hiXY"` will fail because `y.name` will return `undefined` because there is no getter for `name`. You need:

```
class Y extends X {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  get name(){
    return super.name;
  }

  set name(name) {
    super.name = name;
    this._name += "Y";
  }
}
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of debugging time.